# Vapor - How do I return a JSON response with a specific Status Code?

Tags: json, httpresponse, vapor

*Disclaimer: this question originally asked on the Vapor help channel on Slack*

Easy question: if I'm sending a response like this

```
let response: ResponseRepresentable = try JSON(node: ["message": "User Created"])`
```

How can I set the status code for the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Response` class directly, like this:

```
let statusCode = Status.other(statusCode: 666, reasonPhrase: "damn it")
let response = Response(status: statusCode, json: JSON(["error": "my error"]))
```

See the [Response Documentation](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/response.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For Vapor 4 (async/await) -

```
struct MyErrorObject: Content {
   var type: String
   var message: String
}
  
let content = MyErrorObject(type: "error", message: "my error")
les response = try await content.encodeResponse(for: req)
response.status = .imaTeapot
return response
```